# Android Crashlytics get full stack trace

Tags: android, crashlytics

Is there a way to get the full stack trace from a report on crashlytics for Android? My report looks like this but gets truncated so I can't see whats actually causing my error

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Migration didn't properly handle: player_table(com.tapmax.football.model.PlayerModel). Expected: TableInfo{name='player_table', columns={skillMoves=Column{name='skillMoves', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, playerName=Column{name='playerName', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, pace=Column{name='pace', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, shooting=Column{name='shooting', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, defending=Column{name='defending', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, playerImageUrl=Column{name='playerImageUrl', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, dribbling=Column{name='dribbling', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, overall=Column{name='overall', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, passing=Column{name='passing', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, playerPosition=Column{name='playerPosition', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, value=Column{name='value', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, physic=Column{name='physic', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, playerNameUnaccented=Column{name='playerNameUnaccented', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, age=Column{name='age', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue=''''}, playerId=Column{name='playerId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, playerPositionCategory=Column{name='playerPositionCategory', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultVal<truncated: 627 chars>
```

Comment: you can watch stack trace at `firebase console`

Comment: same error here, did you solve it ?